# How do I return all documents that contain a relationship of a particular ID in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to search and return all 'plays' based on if a relationship exists in the 'payees' array using mongoose and Node.js.

Here is the schema:

```
const playSchema = new Schema({
   streamer: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
   song: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Song' },
   revenue: { type: Number },
   createdAt: { type: Date },
   payees: [ { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' } ]
});
```

And here is what I am trying to do (just an example):

```
Play.aggregate([{ $match: { payees: { req.user.id } } }]);
```

Comment: How about `Play.aggregate([{ $match: { payees: { mongoose.types.ObjectId(req.user.id) } } }]);` ?

Comment: @mickl That is returning 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'ObjectId' of undefined'. I am importing mongoose in this controller file.

Comment: sorry, try `mongoose.Types.ObjectId`

Comment: Ronald, did you have a chance to check my answer? If so can you please give feedback whether it worked or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) operator.

> The $elemMatch operator matches documents that contain an array field
>   with at least one element that matches all the specified query
>   criteria.

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/flIvgnBSNqh)

Sample route:

```js
router.get("/plays", async (req, res) => {
  const userId = req.user.id;

  try {
    let docs = await Play.find({
      payees: {
        $elemMatch: {
          $eq: userId
        }
      }
    });

    res.send(docs);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).send("Something went wrong");
  }
});
```